# Может кто-нибудь объяснить, как написать onBindViewHolder для адаптера карточки?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, adapter

У меня есть карточка и я пытаюсь написать к ней адаптер. Как правильно написать `onBindViewHolder` в адаптере?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView cvUser;
    TextView cvLocation;
    ImageView cvPhoto;
    TextView cvContent;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_feed, parent, false));
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cvUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_user);
        cvLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_location);
        cvPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        cvContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
    }
}
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    // Установим количество элементов списка в RecyclerView.
    private static final int LENGTH = 18;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return LENGTH;
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: А данные, которые нужно отображать на этих карточках где? Сейчас ваш адаптер не принимает никаких данных для отображения и ,собственно, в `onBindViewHolder()` писать и нечего, так как он служит для связи данных (ту информацию, что нужно показать) и элементов на экране (то, в чем ее показать TextView, ImageView и тп.)

Comment: Хорошо, а как написать прописать textview и imageview, чтобы адаптер сумел их принять для отображения?

Comment: Вы же "прописали" какие то cvUser, cvLocation cvPhoto и тд. - они должны быть на разметке `card_feed.xml`, обращаться, как в ответе на ваш вопрос написано. НО! пока у вас не появятся данные (то, что нужно, собственно, отобразить в списке) - а их по прежнему нет и что они из себя представляют вы упорно скрываете - ваш адаптер не будет **ничего отображать**, сколько бы TextView вы не "прописывали" сами или спрашивали как это сделать у других.

Answer (score 1):

В `onBindViewHolder` просто назначайте данные вьюхам:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.cvUser.setText("text"); 
}
```